# javascript Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have apply pwa in my web site (my web site with symfony 4) but i have error in google chrome ..service  worker is not created but in firefox is created and this is error display in chrome

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

code :

manifest.json:

```
{
  "lang" : "en",
  "dir" : "ltr",
  "name" : "test",
  "short_name" : "test",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "public/img/icon72x72.png",
    "sizes": "72x72",
    "type": "image/png"
  },{
    "src": "public/img/icon96x96.png",
    "sizes": "96x96",
    "type": "image/png"
  },{
    "src": "public/img/icon144x144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png"
  },{
    "src": "public/img/icon-48x48.png",
    "sizes": "48x48",
    "type": "image/png"
  },{
    "src": "public/img/icon512x512.png",
    "sizes": "152x152",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "public/img/icon-192x192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
  }],
  "theme_color" : "#1a1a1a",
  "background_color" : "#1a1a1a",
  "start_url" : "/",
  "display" : "standalone",
  "orientation" : "natural"
}
```

Gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';
    // Include Gulp & Tools We'll Use
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    gulp.task('generate-service-worker', function(callback) {
        var path = require('path');
        var swPrecache = require('sw-precache');
        var rootDir = 'public';
        swPrecache.write(path.join(rootDir, 'service-worker.js'), {
            staticFileGlobs: [rootDir + '/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif}'],
            stripPrefix: rootDir,
            navigateFallback: '/',
            runtimeCaching: [{
                urlPattern: /\/planet/,
                handler: 'cacheFirst'
            }],
            verbose: true
        }, callback);
    });
```

also when page is loaded it launch this code :

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/service-worker.js', { scope: '/' })
        .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
    });
}
```

and when I launch this command : gulp generate-service-worker it create file service-worker in directory public

Comment: any help please

Comment: Add a catch handler to the registration code to see possible errors there